# Live space used by Cassandra CF

Tags: cassandra

So I have been facing some performance issues and with one of my apps and was trying to understand if it is linked to the space being used by Cassandra. Here are the cfstats obtained on the CF :

```
    SSTable count: 4
    Space used (live): 58123071
    Space used (total): 58123071
    Space used by snapshots (total): 0
    Off heap memory used (total): 78360
    SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.27312902549932555
    Number of keys (estimate): 37373
    Memtable cell count: 30476
    Memtable data size: 1002302
    Memtable off heap memory used: 0
    Memtable switch count: 25
    Local read count: 2177337
    Local read latency: 0.273 ms
    Local write count: 203794
    Local write latency: 0.015 ms
    Pending flushes: 0
    Bloom filter false positives: 74
    Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
    Bloom filter space used: 51824
    Bloom filter off heap memory used: 51792
    Index summary off heap memory used: 22536
    Compression metadata off heap memory used: 4032
    Compacted partition minimum bytes: 104
    Compacted partition maximum bytes: 1916
    Compacted partition mean bytes: 889
    Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 14.242626658160864
    Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 19.0
    Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
    Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
```

Is the amount of live space being used here a problem or is it acceptable ? Is the read latency within tolerable limits? Running Cassandra 2.1.11

Comment: Can you describe the performance problem? How is your cluster build (nodes, hardware)? 60MB of data is quite small, latency looks also good.

Comment: All of this data is completely acceptable. I'd be interested in the output of `nodetool cfhistograms` for this table. Perhaps you have some large partitions? Also, take a look in system.log. Grep for `GCInspector`. See if you have large GC pauses. With G1GC, my pauses are around 200ms. Without more info, it's hard to say.